# How to make EntityManager's flush to flush only certain entity instances?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

My issue is that EntityManager's flush method is writing in the database all the operations buffered by the persist method. No problem with that, BUT sometimes changes get written in other context without me knowing about it. Let me show you an example:

```php
class ServiceA{
   public function __construct(private UserRepository $userRepository){}
   
   public function foo(){
      $user = $this->userRepository->find(1);
      $user->setName('newName');
      $this-userRepository->add($user, true); // second argument means that I do flush
   }
}

class ServiceB{
    public function __construct(
        private VisitRepository $visitRepository,
        private ServiceA $serviceA
    ){}

    public function bar(){
        $visit = $this->visitRepository->find(2);
        $visit->setSomething(2);
        $this->visitRepository->add($visit, false); // second argument means that I don't want to flush
        // Some other SELECTS here via the visitRepository, usage of setters and the persist method, but without flushing
        
        $this->serviceA->foo(); // Inside here the previous persisted instances in this context got flushed by the UserRepository's add method.

        $this->visitRepository->flush() // wrapper of EntityManager's flush method. which did not flush anything.
    }
}
```

The Repository's add method is a wrapper of EntityManager's persist and optional flush. Like this:

```
public function add(Visit $entity, bool $flush = false): void
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);

        if ($flush) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }
```

Then, in my example it doesn't matter if you inject the EntityManager or a Repository to persist and flush.
So, the problem is that the EntityManager (inside the repositories, or even if it was injected as EntityManager in ServiceA or ServiceB), flushes everything, then my problem is that sometimes deep services are flushing changes done in other layers of my app without me noticing. So far it has not been a problem for me, but I can see a design problem here (on my side).

How do you tackle this issue? Do you have any design idea to apply to sort this out. Or, is there any way to wrap only certain operations within the flush method so it only writes in the DB the operations of the context?

I imagine something like this as a solution to accurate the operations that the Entity flushes:

```
$otherContextEntityManager->persist($bar);

$thisContextEntityManager->persist($something)
$thisContextEntityManager->persist($foo);

$thisContextEntityManager->flush(); // Only $something and $foo get written in the DB

$otherContextEntityManager->persist($james);
$otherContextEntityManager->flush(); // Only $bar and $james get written in the DB.
```

Maybe to make some EntityManager as a not shared service?

Comment: there are different strategies in doctrine to track changes. the default is to flush all changes. detaching entities you don't want flushed is an option, changing the change tracking policy could also be appropriate, depending on your use case ... https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#change-tracking-policies ... however. Having two entity managers is always extremely annoying (and I would shy away from that if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine's EntityManager flushes all the changes to managed entities within the current unit of work.

Detach the entity you want to exclude from the flush
$this->entityManager->detach($entity);

Note: Do not pass detached objects to the persist operation.

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. As far as I see, you haven't explained how to flush only a single instance